# Proof with binary associative operation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations

I need help with a proof. Also determine what it means.

Let $S\times S\longrightarrow S $ be a binary and associative operation written as
$(x,y) \mapsto xy$. Assume that for each $x\in S$, there exists a unique $ x^*\in S$ satisfying $ xx^*x=x$ and $x^*xx^*=x^*$.

Let $e $ and $f $ be elements of $S $ such that $e=e\cdot e = e^2$ and $ f=f^2$. Show that $e=e^*$ and $ ef = (ef)^2$.

Comment: Is S ring?is addition defined on S?

Comment: There is nothing else defined the this proof.

Comment: Hint: Let $b=ef$ show that $b^*=fb^*=b^*e$. Deduce that $(b^*)^2=b^*$ and that $b={b^*}^*=b^*$.

Comment: There is something fishy about this; are $e$ and $f$ existentially or universally quantified? In other words: are you being asked to show that for all $e$ and $f$ that satisfy that $e = e*2$ and $f = f^2$ is it the case that $e = e^2$ and $ef = (ef)^2$? If you are, then the first part of he conclusion is trivial.

Comment: I assume you meant show that if $e=e^2$ and $f=f^2$, then $ef=(ef)^2$.

Comment: I fixed it. i meant $e=e^*$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fact 1:** For any $x \in S$ the uniqueness requirement of $x^*$ implies that if for some $y\in S$ the identities $xyx=x$ and $yxy=y$ hold, then $y=x^*$.

Using Fact 1 since $eee=e$ it immediately follows that $e^*=e$.

Let $b=ef$, then by assumption there is unique $b^*$ such that
$$bb^*b=b \text{ and } b^*bb^*=b^*
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
(1)$$ i.e. 
$$efb^*ef=ef\text{ and }b^*efb^*=b^*.
$$
It follows that $$b(fb^*)b= effb^*ef = efb^*ef = ef = b\text{ and } (fb^*)b(fb^*)=fb^*effb^*=fb^*efb^*=f (b^*efb^*) = fb^*$$ and so (by Fact 1) $fb^*=b^*$. Similarly $$b(b^*e)b = efb^*eef=ef=b\text{ and }(b^*e)b(b^*e)=b^*e$$ and so (by Fact 1) $b^*e=b^*$.
Therefore $$(b^*)^2 = (b^*e)(fb^*) = b^*(ef)b^*=b^*bb^*=b^*.$$ It follows that $b^*b^*b^*=b^*$ and hence (by Fact 1) ${b^*}^*=b^*$. On the other hand ${b^*}^*=b$ by Fact 1 using (1). This means that
$$
(ef)^2=b^2=({b^*}^*)^2=(b^*)^2=b^*={b^*}^*=b=ef$$
as desired.